# How does Magento deliver mail?

Tags: email, magento, smtp

I have noticed that there are no explicit mail settings in Magento on which SMTP server to use to send mail.

For example; I could setup my mail to indicate that it is coming from `test@mydomain.com`, while at the same time using Google Apps for mail. And, eventhough the SMTP server settings are not possible to setup in a default Magento install. Magento still manages to deliver the mail. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does what Zend does.

Have a look in /lib/Zend/Mail/

Or check their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Magento sends emails using `Zend_Mail` component.

However, you can assign custom SMTP settings using free [SMTP Pro extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html).